# C# XNA TouchPanel.GetState().Count is returning 0

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna, monogame

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // TODO: Add your update logic here
    TouchCollection touchCollection = TouchPanel.GetState();
    foreach (TouchLocation tl in touchCollection)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("THE SCREEN IS NAW");
        if (tl.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("THE SCREEN IS PRESSED");
        }
    }
    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

So I have an update function to my game, and the update function definitely runs every frame. Note that the following code has been used by me in many other games and it works perfectly. Not to mention that it has been taken directly off the documentations with minimal adjustments. No Debugging output comes out of anything that goes into the Foreach. When I do Debug.Writeline(touchCollection.Count), only 0 outputs, no matter what I do to my phone screen. And last time I checked, my phone screen is perfectly fine.

Does anyone have any recommendations in attempting to solve this error?

Or even better, has anyone experienced this error?

I've tried cleaning the solution, rebuild, and even create a brand new project. When I created a brand new project, the same happened even if it had no code other than this.

Comment: What type of Phone are you using? Is it a Windows Phone or are you attempting to build an Iphone/Android game? Did you try running the code in an emulator?

Comment: @JoshSiegl He has the question tagged with Windows Phone 8.

Comment: Good catch @craftworkgames I didn't notice the tag. The best thing I could tell you is to try it in an emulator.

Comment: If it works in XNA or other devices (including windows) it's likely a bug in MonoGame. You'll either need to dive into the MonoGame source code yourself or perhaps report it on the MonoGame forums / github site.

Comment: It worked on XNA. It is definitely a bug from Monogame.

Comment: Are you remembering to register for TouchPanel.EnabledGestures ? The example of it not working "with no other code than this" make sense, since you need to Enable Gestures.